# getBoundingClientRect does not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dom, getboundingclientrect

I have built a component that will determine its opening direction based on its dimension and position in the window. I used getBoundingClientRect() function on a react-dom node. Now i have updated some of project packages including react and react-dom to 16.3.2. Now I get a compile error:

```
Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'Element | Text'
```

here is a piece of code that use this function:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.containerElement);

if (!node) {
  return;
}

let vertical: Vertical_Direction;
if (verticalDirection === Vertical_Direction.DOWN_UP) {
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const height: number = Math.min(containerHeight, node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
```

Any help or suggestion to achieve this functionality will be appreciated.

Edit2: the cause of this problem is updating @types/react-dom to 16.0.5 version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `getBoundingClientRect` function only exists on the `Element` class, and not `Text`, so you'll need to cast the type of your element like so:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.containerElement) as Element
```

An alternative, safer route would be to check the instance type at runtime, and typescript will intelligently cast the type after the check. But as you can see, it might be a little unnecessarily verbose for this case:

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.containerElement)

// ...

if (!(node instanceof Element)) return

// type of node should be Element
```

Either way, go with whatever you prefer.

Comment: thanks. it worked. I wonder why they change that in this version. @kingdaro

Comment: Sure :) and probably for correctness, since, if the component returns a string from its render method, you'll get back a text node, as the new type suggests